# Creating a variable directly after rails server loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization, text-classification

I am trying to utilize the [classifier gem](https://github.com/cardmagic/classifier) to classify quotes as either "happy" or "sad". Right now, I have the app configured such that any new POST requests train the classifier by using the following command `bayes.train_happy "I am very happy"` in `app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb`

This works whenever adding new quotes while the server is running. However, whenever the server either shuts down or restarts (constantly during development), the variables `bayes` gets deleted, such that when I restart the server the quotes are saved in the database, but `bayes` becomes empty.

Essentially, I want to be able to call the following block of code directly after the server starts, such that a user can call the classifier that has already been built directly after the server starts.

```
bayes = Classifier::Bayes.new 'happy', 'sad'

Quote.all.each do |quote|
    eval("bayes.train_#{quote.classification} quote.body.upcase")
    puts "wrote {#{quote.body}} to bayes"
end
```

where `Quote` is defined as the following in `db/schema.rb`

```
create_table "quotes", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "body"
    t.string   "classification"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create any file in `initializers` folder and put your code there. Make sure you have all dependencies included if any. Rails will load and execute it during server loading

Comment: If I am interpreting you correctly, this is not working. I added a file at ```intializers/bayes.rb``` with the desired code as its only contents. However, when I try and access it by adding ```<%= bayes %>``` to the top of a page, I get a new error:
```undefined local variable or method `bayes'```

Comment: You need to store bayes somewhere to access it later from your page.  ```Rails.application.config.bayes``` is one option.  A redis or similar storage would be better especially if ```bayes``` is in any way a complex structure.